# Basic IPTables setup for OpenVPN/HTTP/HTTPS server

Tags: linux, security, centos, iptables, openvpn

I'm trying to get a basic IPTables setup on my server which will allow HTTP/SSH access, as well as enable the use of the server as an OpenVPN tunnel. The following is my current rule setup - the problem is OpenVPN queries (port 1194) seemed to be getting dropped as a result of this ruleset.

Pinging a website while logged into the VPN results in teh response:

Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
92 bytes from 10.8.0.1: Destination Port Unreachable

When I clear the IPTable rules pinging from the VPN works fine. Any ideas?

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i ! lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT
```

Answer (score 1):

Your VPN server(and client) is configured on TCP or on UDP ? You open just TCP.
Put a log before the reject rules to see what is refused by your firewall : you can then change your rules accordingly.

Comment: both are configured for TCP. How do I put a log before the reject rules?

Comment: just before the REJECT lines put : 
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG

I think something else : you VPN works, right ? You are connected ? The problem, then, is when a packet come from tun0 (VPN interface) to eth0, it is the FORWARD rule which is used. And on your FORWARD rule, you have only REJECT. So define what you authorize in your VPN

Comment: Hi - yes the VPN does work with IPTables disabled. I would like to authorize all activity from my VPN - basically I want to use my VPN to encrypt all traffic from my laptop when I'm at an Internet Cafe, library, etc... as well as restrict access to my home network to my VPNs IP.

Comment: Then open the trafic in FORWARD to allow the VPN to communicate with outside. Think to add the interfaces to define if the connection come from outside or from inside